# How can I use a custom module inside a doctest?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

```
mod simulation;

use simulation::factory::FactoryType;
```

works fine in `main.rs`, but not in a doctest inside `simulation/factory.rs`:

````
impl product_type::ProductType for FactoryType {
    /// Lorem Ipsum
    ///
    /// # Examples
    ///
    /// ```
    /// use simulation::factory::FactoryType;
    ///
    /// ...
    /// ```
    fn human_id(&self) -> &String {
        ...
    }
}
````

`cargo test` gives me the error

```
---- simulation::factory::human_id_0 stdout ----
    <anon>:2:9: 2:19 error: unresolved import `simulation::factory::FactoryType`. Maybe a missing `extern crate simulation`?
<anon>:2     use simulation::factory::FactoryType;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
thread 'simulation::factory::human_id_0' panicked at 'Box<Any>', /home/rustbuild/src/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-linux/build/src/libsyntax/diagnostic.rs:192
```

How can I get doctests to work?

Comment: If you're creating a binary (e.g. if one has `src/main.rs` instead of `src/lib.rs`) then you can't use the functions from it in a doctest: doc tests import the crate they're from as a library (if it is one).

Comment: Please take the time to create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) when asking for help. As you've currently stated your question, we have to do a lot of guessing to know exactly what exists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you write a doc test, you have to act as the *user of your code would*. Given these files:

**src/lib.rs**

````
pub mod simulation {
    pub mod factory {
        pub struct FactoryType;

        impl FactoryType {
            /// ```
            /// use foo::simulation::factory::FactoryType;
            ///
            /// let f = FactoryType;
            /// assert_eq!(42, f.human_id())
            /// ```
            pub fn human_id(&self) -> u8 { 41 }
        }
    }
}
````

**src/main.rs**

```
extern crate foo;
use foo::simulation::factory::FactoryType;

fn main() {
    let f = FactoryType;
    println!("{}", f.human_id());
}
```

Everything works. Note that in **main.rs**, you have to say `extern crate`, then all your references need to include the crate name. The doctest is the same, except the `extern crate` is automatically included for you.

Answer (score 3):

As huon-dbaupp noted, bin crates cannot be imported from doc tests.

The solution is to define most of your code as a library crate and have one binary that is just a shell around that.

For example, [racer](https://github.com/phildawes/racer) employs this technique.

Comment: The same was true of C# until they fixed it for tests in exes. Come on rust, remove the gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

tldr: just add `# fn main() {}` to the end of your doc test, or add `#[path = "..."]` attribute to `mod`.

Follows are a note I wrote recently when writing a doc test. It will help you using `mod` in your doc tests:

This is used for doc tests.

Some traits in this crate need `protobuf::MessageFull`, such as `ProtoLocal: PathInfo + MessageFull`, which is auto implemented for all `T: PathInfo + MessageFull`.

To write `ProtoLocal` doc test, we have to got a struct (let's name it `Msg`) that satisfies `MessageFull` and `PathInfo` traits.

However, it is too hard to mamually implemente `MessageFull`. (`MessageFull` is generated by the famous [`protobuf`](https://protobuf.dev), the basis of kinds of `RPC`s). If we generate and `pub use` it in `my_crate`, we cannot `impl PathInfo for Msg` due to rust's orphan rule (We all know that document test is a kind of integration test).

```rust
// in doc test
use my_crate::test_utils::Msg;
// `Msg` is in `my_crate`'s test_utils, which implemented `MessageFull`
use my_crate::{PathInfo, ProtoLocal};

impl PathInfo for Mag { ... } // <- this violate rust's orphan rule
```

Instead we can:

```rust
// in doc test
// Included through `mod`.
mod test_utils;
use test_utils::msg::Msg;
use my_crate::{PathInfo, ProtoLocal};

impl PathInfo for Mag { ... }
// Here `Msg` is part of the doc test, just like `common` introduced in offical book about integration tests,
// and won't violate rust's orphan rule
# fn main() {}    // <- This is essential, or an error will be raised
```

Caution: You have to add `# fn main() {}` at the end of the test, or an error will be raised. I don't know the reason right now. Maybe [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html). You can use `#[path = "..."] instead of` # fn main() {}`.

Related [document](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html#submodules-in-integration-tests)

[module-system](https://aloso.github.io/2021/03/28/module-system.html)

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood the questioner's meaning. But my answer may be useful for those who really want `mod` in doc tests and this page is the first result of google about `rust using mod in doc tests`.